# Feedback on rejected edit with disparate reasons

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I made an edit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126365/3079302), which was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12530100). I have learned that [posting a question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286206/3079302) is how one should look for clarification on a rejected review.

My intention, as outlined in the edit comment, was to expand the given example (adding a possible feature that is illustrated in the official examples), and to provide a link to a more detailed explanation and examples of the syntax. The link that was already included in the answer does not point to these.

However, three out of five reviewers rejected this edit, each with a different reason:

1. > This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
2. > This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.
3. > This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I would like to learn why and how my edit made the answer harder to read, it is superfluous, intents to address the author, and deviates from the original intent. I am genuinely looking to improve my contribution to the community, so I would like to avoid making bad edits.

Comment: Personally, I think adding the link was fine, but adding the extra text to the example was superfluous; " - first number" doesn't really increase the amount of information available to the user of the `sum(a, b)` function.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The question is about documentation. The function given in the example is trivial. My point was to make it clear that it is possible to add a description of the variable, which would then be parsed by jsdoc.

Comment: I was telling you why your edit was superfluous. My suggestion is, as Servy has written, next time create a new answer which has all of the content you want (perhaps including a non-trivial example), rather than editing an existing answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ok, I understand what you say. Although I don't agree with you nor with @EricD -- if the question is about documentation, the target user here is the guy writing the documentation, not the user of the function itself, hence I don't consider `- insert variable description here` something superfluous. I'm not discussing this, I see your point and I will take it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content, not for you to add your own original content.  If you have new content you want to add to this question, then you can post your own answer, or, if the information isn't substantial enough to merit an answer, then as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That looks to me like yet another different reason. Nevertheless, [according to a moderator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288433/3079302), edits also serve to `adding supplementary (and complementary) information`. Also, the previous edit just added new content, and it was [approved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8230100). Could you please expand your answer in order to address these points?

Comment: @iled the fact that one person said one thing doesn't make it policy.  The policy is that edits shouldn't be adding new content.  That an inappropriate edit was once approved is unfortunate, but by no means uncommon.  Too many reviewers just approve anything without looking closely.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying. I'm not trying to make a point here, I'd just like to have this clear in my head -- it is not one person saying the policy, it looks like it is the [policy itself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing): `Common reasons for edits include: [...] To add related resources or hyperlinks`, and then, if I had added it as a comment, the Help Center also says `To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place`. So, what makes the difference between that and what I did?

Comment: I wouldn't have rejected the edit because of the link - but I would have rejected the edit nonetheless, because adding "first number" and "second number" to "number a" and "number b" *is* a superfluous edit (but yeah, I guess there's room for opinion here). And the link could be a comment indeed anyway.

Comment: @iled the line of adding information from comments refers to adding information *the author* posted in comments, not anything anyone posted in comments.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, but I can only take that as your opinion. Reading the linked page, that is far from obvious. The page in the Help Center is about editing posts that belong to someone else; of course the author can edit own posts. If the policy is to allow someone to edit a post to include some information that *only the author* left as a comment in his or her *own post*, and *not* information left by *other users*, then it should be clearly stated. You still didn't address my other point about adding content. I can't accept your answer while it is going against what's written in the Help Center.